# Remove file's substring to index in terminal

Tags: bash, file, shell, terminal, rename

I have a file list. They are following this pattern : _000n_NAME.PNG (with n the file number)

In terminal (Linux or Mac OS) is it possible to delete '*000n*' in a single command for all my files ?

Comment: Do you want to remove the underscores as well? Are the files in the same directory or are they scattered over several (sub)directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed can do the job:

```
sed 's/^_[0-9]*\(_.*\)$/_\1/'
```

If you want to strip underscores (before & after numbers) also:

```
sed 's/^_[0-9]*_\(.*\)$/\1/'
```

**Full Script:**

```
while read f; do
    mv "$f" $(echo "$f"|sed 's#^.*_[0-9]*_\(.*\)$#\1#')
done < <(find . -name "_0*_NAME.PNG")
```

Comment: @Kent: Sure I will add that.

Comment: I tried `rename 's/000\([0-9]\)/\1/' _000*` but it's not working.

Comment: @fedorqui: That's not the sed I suggested.

Comment: Yes, @anubhava , I was just commenting that I tried a `sed` expression and worked and then moved to `rename` and did not work.

Comment: Ok got you, I posted full script for renaming. (On OSX there is no rename)

Answer (score 2):

You can use that :

```
  find . -iname '_000n*.png' | sed -e 's/\(_000n_\(.*.png\)\)/\1 \2/g' | xargs -n 2 mv
```

- find : will list all files named _000n*.png in current folder, thus matching your need
- sed : will extract the correct part and display original + new name
- xargs -n 2 : will pass arguments to next command grouping by 2
- mv : will rename

tested with `_000n_toto1.png`, `_000n_toto2.png` and other files in folder

Comment: can use much simpler sed `sed -e 'p;s/_[0-9]*_//'` or `sed -e 'p;s/_[0-9]*n_//'` but +1 for using `xargs -n2` ;)